# Usar "text-overflow" com "height"

Tags: css

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma div, eu apliquei a essa `div text-overflow`, para ela respeita o *`width`* da div e adicionar as reticencias(...), mas até então, ela só respeita o *`width`*, e eu queria que esse elemento do css, respeitasse o *`width`* e o *`height`*, ou seja, ele desse quebra de linha até chegar no limite do *`height`*, e quando chegar no final da ultima linha, com o limite do *`height`*, ele aplicasse as reticencias, alguém sabe como fazer?

Código css:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
word-wrap: break-word;
width:100%;
height: 35px;
color:#FF8000;
```

Comment: Talvez [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/) ajude.

Comment: Esse efeito não funciona no firefox, será que tem algum jeito de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

É possível adicionar reticências em um elemento de bloco quando o texto tiver **apenas uma linha**. De outra forma, somente com um pouco de programação, como é mostrado em outra resposta.

Para setar essa propriedade em `CSS`, o código básico é esse:

```
.reticencias{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Resposta tardia mas funcional. O CSS abaixo aplicado na div (ou parágrafo) onde o texto está, limita a exibição em número de linhas, e não em altura (height).

```css
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3; /** número de linhas que você quer exibir */
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34559614/13185945

Answer (score 1):

Não há como exibir apenas uma parte do texto e ainda adicionar reticências ao final com as propriedades `CSS`. Você precisaria usar comandos nativos da linguagem que estiver utilizando (PHP, ASP, etc...), porém elas apenas cortariam o texto, sem adicionar as reticências.

Para fazer o que você quer, corretamente, é preciso criar a função:

```
<?php
function tamanho_texto($str, $length) {
     return substr($str, 0, $length)."...";
}
?>
```

E depois, quando for escrever o texto, definir quantos caracteres deseja que ele tenha, de acordo com o tamanho da sua `div`.

```
<?php
echo tamanho_texto("TESTE DE TEXTO", 8);
?>
```

E o seu retorno seria: `TESTE DE...`